# Unity can't hear sound

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a football game and i want it to play a sound every time i score a goal but i can't hear any sound.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class gol : MonoBehaviour
{
public AudioClip audioclip;
public AudioSource audiosource;
public bool golmu = false;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
   
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    

    if (golmu == true && !audiosource.isPlaying)
    {
        audiosource.clip = audioclip;
        audiosource.Play();
    }
}

public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "gol")
    {
        
        golmu = true;
    }

    else
    {
        golmu = false;
    }
}

public void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "gol")
    {
        golmu = false;
    }
}


}
```

I tried without using `AudioClip` but it's not working. Putting the `AudioSource` component in another object too. I tried every code I saw but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have a listener?

Comment: Yes, i have in the camera components.